# How to scale an image to its original size by CSS?

Tags: html, css

I enlarge an image by CSS as

HTML

```
<img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg" />
```

CSS

```
img {
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.2s ease;
}

img:hover {
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wox8qb7j/)

Instead of enlarging the scale by a given factor (here 2), how can I enlarge the photo to its original size and aspect ratio?

Instead of hovered size of `640x640`, I want to show the original size of `550x368` upon hovering.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `:hover` class to this:

```
img:hover {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

or

```
img:hover {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```